# RDLC error when deployment of software: The report definition is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services

Tags: c#, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

I have this C# application which runs perfectly on production but gives an error on deployment. And the issue is very vague.

**The report definition is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. This could be the result of publishing a report definition of a later version of Reporting Services, or that the report definition contains XML that is not well-formed or the XML is not valid based on the Report Definition schema. Details: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.**

Edit:
I have browsed more and some suggestions were to add the 3 MS reporting dll, but these are already on the bin folder.

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to install the SSRS Report Viewer redistributable package that matches the version that the report was created for.  There are _at least_ 4 versions that I know of offhand.  What version of SSRS did you use to create the report?

Comment: Hi, does this mean I do not need to republish the application? I still have to check the SSRS version cause I'm not the developer of the application.

Comment: I'm not sure how your application is written, it's possible that it may just work once you install the redistributable package.  It's also possible that your application directly referenced an older version of the library that doesn't support features used in an RDLC created by a newer version.  If that's the case, you will probably need to republish after making sure that all the version numbers match.

Comment: After publishing the application, just republish your reports related code.